# version support in android

Tags: android

HI i developed application in android 1.5 and i make it for support screens in large and medium and small through coding if i release android 1.5 on market it will appear in all android version phone market (android 1.5 +) .am i get application in droid,small device market and it is work fine or not

Thanks in Advance

Aswan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Please Note the 1.6 and later version devices's only supports the multiple screen. If you create your app in 1.5 you have to main concentrate on the -v4 attribute. study carefully the Document. Topic Name: [Strategies for Legacy Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies).